# MIFARE Plus X not responding to REQA

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid, mifare

I'm using MFRC522 Reader with an Arduino. I managed to get it working with MIFARE Classic 1K, using [this library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid). I got some MIFARE Plus X from the store, and for all I know they should AT LEST respond to REQA but none of them does.

What could be the possible reason? I'm using 100%ASK modulation, CRC Initial value set to 0x6363 (tried 0xFFFF too, doesn't work). Is it possible that those cards are of type B? Or maybe I'm missing something and I should add some settings commands while initializing the reader? Like change the communication speed to some other value?

Comment: Yes, MIFARE Plus are Type A cards and should respond to the same REQA command that MIFARE Classic cards (or actually any Type A cards) respond to. Are you continuously polling for new commands using REQA or are you just issuing the command once? Are you sending the REQA command *after* you put the card on the reader antenna? Did you build the reader yourself or do you use a ready-made reader board? What size is the reader antenna?

Comment: I am using [this reader](http://cloud7.lbox.me/images/384x384/201306/rfid-rc522-rf-ic-card-sensor-module-blue-silver_evggkz1371097722496.jpg) based on MFRC522 chip [(datasheet)](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf). It's connected to an Arduino, and the only thing I'm trying to get is the ATQA from the card. I am continously sending REQA through the reader, and check for any data available from the card. I am getting the ATQA from every MIFARE Classic 1k card, but not with the Plus X's, and I've tried with several. Could it be that they don't work because they're on SL0?

Comment: No, MIFARE Plus (X) will respond to anticollision commands regardless of their security level.

Comment: So basically, if MIFARE Classic works, and Plus X doesn't, with the same program, the case might be that either the card is of Type B, the card is broken (unlikely, tried 5 of them), or there is an issue with the reader? I'm assuming that CRC initial value (0x6363) and the transmision speed (106 kBd) are the same for MIFARE Classic and a Plus X with factory settings. Could it possibly be a problem with the antenna? Or the gain settings? The reader datasheet states that it can be used with MIFARE Plus cards (though not mentioning 'X' type)

Comment: Communication up to the selection is exactly the same for all three chip types (MF Classic, MF Plus (X)). It could be a problem with the antenna/energy transfer/data transfer, but that's difficult to know without performing measurements/tests on that particular hardware.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with MIFARE DESFire EV1 cards. Any MF classic works fine, but the DESFire doesn't respond/isn't detected after the REQA command. I can see this by using the spisniffer.

Answer (score 0):

The reader that you mention does not provide adequate RF power for Mifare Plus X card. It is possible to fix this by replacing L1 and L2 inductors with same inductance (2.2uH) but higher operating current.
I found the answer at this link:
https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/my-experience-of-mfrc522-on-how-to-get-more-rf-power.125863